# If I have the War Caster feat, can I use the Thorn Whip cantrip to stop an enemy caster from escaping using the Dimension Door spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, feats, cantrips, reactions

Assume I am playing a druid or warlock with the [War Caster feat](https://www.dndbeyond.com/feats/war-caster), which allows me to cast single target spells in place of using a melee attack of opportunity. I also know the [*thorn whip*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/thorn-whip) cantrip. A successful hit with *thorn whip* can allow me to pull the target 10 feet. I am facing an opponent with the [*dimension door*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/dimension-door) spell and want to stop them from getting away.

If the enemy spellcaster were leaping or stepping midway through the *dimension door*, would it be possible to cast *thorn whip* using the War Caster feat, hit the target and pull them out, thus preventing them from moving with *dimension door*?

Comment: Welcome to rpg.se! Take the [tour] and see [this meta](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9185/48759) for other places you can find help. Or just ask here in the comments (use @ to ping someone). Before we can answer this question we need to know what system and edition you are playing. The best way to show this is by [edit]ing in the correct system tag (e.g. [tag:dnd-5e]) until then your question may be closed. Good luck and happy gaming!

Answer (score 30):

### The hostile creature’s movement doesn't provoke an opportunity attack from you, so your War Caster feat isn't triggered.

The War Caster feat (PHB 170) says:

> When a hostile creature’s movement provokes an opportunity attack from
>   you, you can use your reaction to cast a spell at the creature, rather
>   than making an opportunity attack. The spell must have a casting time
>   of 1 action and must target only that creature.

The hostile creature’s movement doesn't provoke an opportunity attack from you, so your War Caster feat isn't triggered.

The *Dimension Door* spell description (PHB 233) says:

> You teleport yourself from your current location to any other spot
>   within range. You arrive at exactly the spot desired. It can be a
>   place you can see, one you can visualize, or one you can describe by
>   stating distance and direction, such as "200 feet straight downward"
>   or "upward to the northwest at a 45- degree angle, 300 feet."

*Dimension Door* is a teleportation spell, and teleportation doesn't trigger opportunity attacks.

The rules on opportunity attacks (PHB 195) state:

> You also don't provoke an opportunity attack when you teleport or when
>   someone or something moves you without using your movement, action, or
>   reaction.

Additionally, [spells do what they say they do](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/107637/what-is-the-source-of-the-spells-do-only-what-they-say-they-do-rules-interpret), and the spell [description of Dimension Door does not say it creates a door](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/56174/44723) that you need to pass through; it merely teleports you to the spot within range, so the proposed mechanism to prevent the teleportation from occurring wouldn't work, either.

---

<sub>Thank you to [nick012000](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/39836/nick012000) for contributing the additional note.</sub>

Comment: So the best bet would be to use a counter spell, gotcha.